# Android RecyclerView Provide Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have one Vertical RecyclerView. I have added items in it. It is working fine. Now my issue is when any single item will have so many data, i want my whole RecyclerView to scroll horizontally not that single item.

Here is the UI i have made. [image]

For Inner cell, I am adding view dynamically in Linearlayout.

```
for (int i = 0; i <subItem ; i++) {

        View Cv= Li.inflate(R.layout.custom_cell, holder.ViewLayout, false);
        TextView  textBedInfo = (TextView) Cv.findViewById(R.id.textBedInfo);
        TextView  textRowInfo = (TextView) Cv.findViewById(R.id.textRowInfo);

        textBedInfo.setTypeface(fontBold);
        textRowInfo.setTypeface(fontRegular);

        if(i==0 || i==subItem-1){
            textBedInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textRowInfo.setText((position+1)+" Row");
        }
        else{
            textRowInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ConstantMethod.setBorder(textBedInfo, Color.WHITE,R.drawable.circle);
            textBedInfo.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        holder.ViewLayout.addView(Cv);
    }
```

As you can see in image , last row has too many data so i want my recycler view to scroll horizontally but it's not working.

I have tried by setting `HorizontalScrollView` as parent of `recyclerView` but it also not works. It shows blank view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          tools:context="com.sunbed.reservation.ReservationMapFragment">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerMaps"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This is my main layout. Anyone could help me out for same?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want your `horizontalScrollView` to be the root of your `R.layout.custom_cell` instead

Comment: Yes but it will scroll single cell. Not Whole Recyclerview.  I want to scroll Whole screen

Comment: Maybe put the whole RecyclerView into a ScrollView.

Comment: I have tried by putting RecyclerView inside scrollview but it displays nothing. Also tried by setting RecyclerView's width programmatically but with no luck

Comment: For horizontal scrolling you have to use the HorizontalScrollView : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: I have managed by using HorizontalScrollView inside Scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to implement it. I have removed resyclerview. And used Scrollview. I have added all views dynamically in my scrollview. This is my parent layout in which i have added views.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMap"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMaps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I know, that it will take time to load views when all views are loaded dynamically. But for now i have used this solution. Better answers are always accepted. 
Thanks.